# Which achievements are missable in Batman: Arkham City?

Tags: achievements, batman-arkham-city

Before I get started with games, I always like to know beforehand if there are missable achievements, especially regarding the storyline. For example, in Arkham Asylum, there was the **Party Pooper** achievement near the end, where you had to defeat all the clapping enemies from the Joker's party.

Are there missable achievements like this one in Arkham City? I don't mean things that are *optional* to complete in the first playthrough, like all Riddler Trophies or all upgrades, but achievements that are actually *unable to be acquired* without fulfilling certain criteria.

To clarify, I mean in the base game, *not* including the optional DLC like Catwoman and Robin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I've seen and gained, there is *maybe* only one that is missable. However, you will have a second chance to get it if you go through a New Game Plus to get that achievement.

[image]

**Catch**

This one is not related to the main story, and is related to another achievement **Mystery Stalker**. You only meet a certain person 5 times during the game, and after that they are gone. You have to throw a remote controlled batarang at them.

Comment: Stop the clock is simply a side mission. Not missable. Catch is the only missable achievement.

Comment: @JamesJiao Thanks, wasn't 100% if it was story related. Updated

Comment: batman can catch it himself and it will count.

Comment: @user49590 - My recollection is that you canNOT catch it yourself in Arkham City.  (This is different from the similar trochievement in Asylum.)

Comment: Reading this here drove me crazy, cause I can't remember doing it, but it seems like this achievement doesn't exist on PC: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66018/is-it-possible-to-get-the-catch-achievement-on-pc