# Is it possible to get the "Catch" achievement on PC?

Tags: achievements, batman-arkham-city

While looking around for information on other achievements, I've found [this one](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/batman-arkham-city/achievement/57323-Catch.html) that doesn't show up in the Steam achievements list. Thinking that it was a "secret" achievement, I've tried to do as said in the comments,

> throwing a remote batarang to Azrael.

He caught it, but no achievement popped up. Am I missing something? Is "Catch" a Xbox-only achievement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [Steam achievement list](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/BatmanArkhamCity/achievements), it seems indeed the PC version of the game doesn't have the **Catch** achievement or equivalent.

Comment: I think it's more likely GameFAQs just copied the achievement list from the xbox. Steam copies of Arkham City still use GFWL and looking at "progress" on xbox.com for the game, the achievement isn't listed as obtainable.

Comment: I completely forgot that I could check the achievemnts also on GFWL. Sadly, as you already said, "Catch" isn't available.

Comment: What a particularly random thing to leave out :/